# Change button text with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a "Save" button. When I click this button, it disappears and an "Unsave" button shows up. The following Javascript works just fine:

```
    function saveFunction(id){
        var ie=document.all&&!window.opera? document.all : 0
        var frmObj=ie? ie[id] : document.getElementById(id)
        var toObj=ie? ie['unsave'] : document.getElementById('unsave')
        frmObj.style.display='none';
        toObj.style.display='inline';
        toObj.value=frmObj.innerHTML
    }
```

Here are my buttons:

```
<form id="save-form" method="" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
    <button id="save" type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this.id)">Save</button>
    <button id="unsave" type="button" class="hide" onclick="unsaveFunction(this.id)">Unsave</button>
</form>
```

And here's the CSS (to hide the "Unsave" button):

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

The problem is that I also want the "Unsave" button (when clicked) to disappear and the "Save" button to show up. So, right now it only works in one way: `Save --> Unsave`, but I also want it to work the other way around: `Unsave --> Save`.

I tried to duplicate the Javascript function, change its properties so that it'd work the other way around (see `unsaveFunction()`) but it doesn't. I'm kinda stuck there. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: why you don't use JQuery to simplify your solution ?

Comment: @MateeGojra for such a simple stuff, no need to load jquery on the page.

Comment: @jai i think you hate jQuery...:D Jquery paradox...:D

Comment: @BuggyParadox i learnt javascript from jquery. I like to use it only when it needs to be. Not for everything.

Comment: ok by the way, Why you are answering on behalf of Maasha??

Comment: Did I? Really. She just posted a clean question and you are polluting this space with answers which OP hasn't tagged :D...

Comment: Why not going advance? Jquery is more easy and reliable instead of js...I hope you understand. I advice the person who asked question to use jquery instead of js, it will be perfect choice...

Comment: @BuggyParadox naaah. too much work this side.

Comment: Then give us some work related to jquery...:D We are in search of it...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, hope it helps.

```
   function hideOnClk(id){
             if(id == "save"){
               document.getElementById("unsave").style.display="block";
               document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
             }else{
               document.getElementById("save").style.display="block";
               document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
             }
          }

<form id="save-form" method="" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <button id="save" type="button" onclick="hideOnClk(this.id)">Save</button>
        <button id="unsave" type="button" class="hide" onclick="hideOnClk(this.id)">Unsave</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using jQuery**

Try  to use toggleClass

```
 <form id="save-form" method="" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <button id="save" type="button" onclick="$('#save').toggleClass('hide');$('#unsave').toggleClass('hide');">Save</button>
        <button id="unsave" type="button" class="hide" onclick="$('#save').toggleClass('hide');$('#unsave').toggleClass('hide');">Unsave</button>
    </form>
```

**Using Javascript**

```
    function myFunction() {
   var element=     document.getElementById("save");
        element.classList.toggle("hide");
  var element=  document.getElementById("unsave");
        element.classList.toggle("hide");
    }

 <form id="save-form" method="" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
            <button id="save" type="button" onclick="myFunction();">Save</button>
            <button id="unsave" type="button" class="hide" onclick="myFunction();">Unsave</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't get if I should use both jQuery and Javascript or either one of them (?)

Comment: @MaashaTheytaz no need to use both. You can use either jQuery or Javascript. its your choice

Comment: If You use jQuery you need to include the library : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

What about one single button with both functionalities?
It starts like a save button, when clicked, it do the save stuff then if becomes a "unsave" button.

See below code to see if it helps:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("saveControl");


btn.onclick = function(){
console.log(btn.classList.value)
  if (btn.classList.contains("saveBtn")){
    //DO SAVE STUFF...
    
    btn.classList.remove("saveBtn")
    btn.classList.add("btnUnsave")
    btn.innerText = "Unsave"
    
  } else {
    //DO UNSAVE STUFF...
    
    btn.classList.add("saveBtn")
    btn.classList.remove("btnUnsave")
    btn.innerText = "Save"
  }
}
```

```css
.saveBtn{
  color:blue
}

.btnUnsave{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="saveControl" class="saveBtn">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy and simple, Regarding your level of programming i don't want to overwhelm you with all the possible ways you can do it.

```js
function saveFunction() {
  // getting the form from the document using the form name attribute 
  let form = document.form;
  // using the buttons names attribute to select theme
  // classList property of any element gives you all the class it has
  // add('class name') adds the specified class
  form.save.classList.add('hide');
  // remove('class name') removes the specified class
  form.unsave.classList.remove('hide');
}

function unsaveFunction() {
  let form = document.form;
  form.unsave.classList.add('hide');
  form.save.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" method="" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
  <button id="save" type="button" onclick="saveFunction()" name="save">Save</button>
  <button id="unsave" type="button" name="unsave" class="hide" onclick="unsaveFunction()">Unsave</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try HTML DOM classList Property Toggle

```
document.getElementById("save").toggle("hide)
document.getElementById("unsave").toggle("hide)
```